# Spivak, Ch. 20, Problem 14: Estimate $\int_0^{0.1} \exp(x^2)dx$ with an error of less than $10^{-5}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

The following is a problem from Chapter 20 of Spivak's *Calculus*.

> 14. Estimate $\int_0^{0.1} \exp(x^2)dx$ with an error of less than $10^{-5}$.

The solution manual says

> $$e^{x^2}=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}+...+\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}+R(x)$$
>
> where
>
> $$|R(x)|\leq \frac{3x^{2n+1}}{(n+1)!}\tag{1}$$
>
> Since
>
> $$\int_0^{0.1}|R(x)|dx\leq \frac{3(.1)^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)(n+1)!}$$
>
> the error will already be $<10^{-5}$ for $n=2$.

**To cut to the chase, my questions are**

- Is it actually possible to use $n=1$ (ie a second order Taylor polynomial instead of a fourth order one) to obtain the desired estimate?
- How did Spivak obtain an expression for the remainder?
- I reach my own answers to these questions below, and I am curious if the steps are correct.

**Now let me go over my attempt at solving this problem,** to show why I have these questions.

$$f(x)=e^x=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{x^{i}}{i!}+\frac{e^t}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$$

$$f(x^2)=e^{x^2}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{x^{2i}}{i!}+\frac{e^t}{(n+1)!}x^{2n+2}$$

where $$R(x)=\frac{e^t}{(n+1)!}x^{2n+2}<\frac{3}{(n+1)!}x^{2n+2}\tag{2}$$

This seems to be similar to $(1)$, but for the exponents on $x$ that are different.

I think the reason for that is that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{x^{2i}}{i!}$ is the Taylor polynomial both of order $2n$ and $2n+1$ for $e^{x^2}$ at $0$.

The remainders for these two Taylor polynomials are $\frac{e^{t_1}}{(n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$ and $\frac{e^{t_2}}{(n+1)!}x^{2n+2}$, respectively, with both $t_1$ and $t_2$ between $0$ and $x$.

If we use the first remainder, since we are integrating from $x$ equals $0$ to $0.1$, the integral of the remainder is

$$\int_0^{0.1} R(x)dx<\int_0^{0.1}\frac{3}{(n+1)!}x^{2n+1}=\left . \frac{3}{(2n+2)(n+1)!}x^{2n+2}\right |_0^{0.1}$$

$$=\frac{3\cdot 0.1^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)(n+1)!}\tag{3}$$

If $n=2$ then $(3)$ is approximately $8.3\cdot 10^{-8}<10^{-5}$.

And this is just like the solution manual.

If we use the second remainder

$$\int_0^{0.1} R(x)dx<\int_0^{0.1}\frac{3}{(n+1)!}x^{2n+2}=\left . \frac{3}{(2n+3)(n+1)!}x^{2n+3}\right |_0^{0.1}$$

$$=\frac{3\cdot 0.1^{2n+3}}{(2n+3)(n+1)!}\tag{4}$$

If $n=1$ then $(4)$ equals $\frac{3\cdot 0.1^5}{5\cdot 3!}=10^{-6}<10^{-5}$.

Therefore, the solution manual seems to be using the first remainder, but could we not have used the second remainder?

**Is the analysis above correct?**

EDIT:

Checking in Maple, I have the following results

$$\int_0^{0.1} (1+x^2)dx= 0.1003333333$$

$$\int_{0}^{ 0.1}\left(1+x^{2}+\frac{x^{4}}{2}\right)dx= 0.1003343333$$

$$\int_0^{0.1} e^{x^2}=0.1003343357$$

$$\int_{0}^{ 0.1}{\mathrm e}^{x^{2}}d x-\int_{0}^{ 0.1}\left(1+x^{2}\right)d x= 1.0024\times 10^{-6}$$

$$\int_{0}^{ 0.1}{\mathrm e}^{x^{2}}d x-\int_{0}^{ 0.1}\left(1+x^{2}+\frac{x^{4}}{2}\right)d x= 2.4\times 10^{-9}$$

Comment: Youmay also consider $F(x)=\int^x_0 e^{t^2}\,dt$ and expand $F$ instead.  It seems that a Taylor  expansion of order 5 will will you the order of accuracy

Comment: I did what you did. I think the solution manual incorrectly wrote the $R(x)$ term...really, it should be $R(x^2)$.